# contour level in matplotlib.pyplot.contour

Tags: matplotlib, contour

matplotlib.pyplot.contour automatically chooses the contour level.

1. Does anybody know how it defines the contour's level? What is the principle/algorithm behind it?
2. The contour looks very smooth: is there any smoothing algorithm of contour drawing?

Any help will be greatly appreciated,

Jenny